# How can I input a value as a string and then input a int value without having two input boxes?

Tags: python, string, input, while-loop, int

I am writing code where the user has to guess a number and input it and where they can type either 'quit', 'QUIT', or 'Quit' and it'll end the program.

I have a while loop that will end the program once they have reached their limit of six tries and have the input() in it where they can guess the number. I know I need to test for the strings,'quit', 'QUIT', or 'Quit' before I convert the input() to an integer, but I don't know how to do so without having an input() that checks for the string and one that checks for the integer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Can you post your code so far?

Comment: I was able to figure it out. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are looking for something like this(python 2.6/7):-

```
lucky_number = 5
tries = 6
while tries:
  inp = raw_input("User input: ")
  if inp.isdigit() and int(inp) == lucky_number:
    return True
  elif inp.lower() == 'quit':
    break
  tries -= 1
return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you input is a string, so there's no harm in just comparing it to `QUIT` before trying to create an `int` object from it.

```
tries = 0
while tries < 6:

    value = raw_input("Enter a number, or 'quit' to quit: ")  # input() in Python 3.x
    if value.upper() == 'QUIT':
        sys.exit()

    try:
        value = int(value)
    except ValueError:
        continue  # Return to the top of the loop for another value

    # Process the input integer...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are converting it into an `int` after taking an input, I am going to assume you are using Python 3.

Try the following in your main loop:

```
a = input()
if(a.isdigit()):
    n = int(a)
    #main code here
else:
    #check for "quit" here as shown below
    if(a.upper == 'QUIT'):  #a.upper() will convert the string into capital letters
        #You need to break from the main loop
        break
```

If you are using Python 2.7 or lower, then replacing `input()` with `raw_input()` in the above example code will solve your problem.

`raw_input()` takes in any type of input, thus solving your problem.